# Populated on MVC form View the TextBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need populate on MVC form `View` the **TextBox** below

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.tDate)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.tDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "Mytextarea2" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.tDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Whit value extract from `controller` (using MySql database) when I have planned this code

```
public DateTime JsonDateTimeToNormal(string jsonDateTime)
{
    jsonDateTime= @"""" + jsonDateTime + @"""";
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(jsonDateTime);
}

...

model.tDate = JsonDateTimeToNormal(GetDateHourById(value).ToString());

...

private static string GetDateHourById(string value)
{
    string sql;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {
        sql = @String.Format(" SELECT ");
        sql += String.Format(" tDate ");
        sql += String.Format(" FROM `dotable` ");
        sql += String.Format(" WHERE tID = @Id;");

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", value);
            con.Open();
            string name = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();

            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

The value memorized on MySql database is

`2020-03-19`

But the `TextBox` is populed with this value

```
/Date(1605481200000)/
```

On the model

```
[Column(TypeName = "date")]
[Display(Name = "Your date")]
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? tDate { get; set; }
```

Help me to do it.

**Debug VS 2109**

[image]

**Solution**

```
const d = new Date(response.tDate.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
const formattedDate = d.getFullYear()+'-'+("0"+(d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'+("0"+d.getDate()).slice(-2)
$('#tDate').val( formattedDate );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you try to make this call with a jquery?

view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.tDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "Mytextarea2" })

$("#document").on("click", ".YouFormCall", function () {
                var date = new Object();
                date.tDate = $(this).closest('tr').find(".Mytextarea2").val();
```

controller:

```
        yourModel date= new yourModel ()
        {
            tDate= date.tDate,
        };
        db.Entry(date).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for help, but I can't rewrite my App MVC, sorry